# Splitting delimited strings with undefined number of delimiters

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, multiple-value

I have a problem, I have the following line of strings

```
0009 - The Good Boy Song
0003 - Alphabet Song
0008 - Flame-thrower Guide
```

I have a split function that currently takes two parameters,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
 @String NVARCHAR(4000),
 @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
AS(
    SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter2,@String) AS endpos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
        FROM Split
        WHERE endpos > 0
)
SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
    'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
FROM Split
)
```

I need to make sure that the ouput is something like

```
Id       Data
0009 The Good Boy Song
0003 Alphabet Song
0008 Flame-thrower Guide
```

and not something like

```
0009 The Good Boy Song
0003 Alphabet Song
0008 Flame
thrower Guide
```

I'm using this on SSRS, where in I'm sending a multiple valued argument, it looks like this as SSRS sends multiple values in CSV form.

```
'0009 - The Good Boy Song,0003 - Alphabet Song,0008 - Flame-thrower Guide'
```

How I update my function to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your function slightly:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Split]
(
 @String NVARCHAR(4000),
 @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
AS(
    SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
        FROM Split
        WHERE endpos > 0
)
, SplitData AS
(
  SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
      'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
  FROM Split
)
SELECT ID
  , NumericData = SUBSTRING(Data, 1, 4)
  , TextData = SUBSTRING
    (
      Data
      , 8
      , len(Data) - 7
    )
FROM SplitData
)
```

This is giving OK results for me.

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fe42/1).

**Edit after comment:**

To prevent issues with the recursion limit you need to set `MAXRECURSION` outside of the function, i.e. when you're calling it with a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Split
(
  N'0009 - The Good Boy Song,0003 - Alphabet Song,0008 - Flame-thrower Guide'
  , N','
)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

You cannot apply the hint in the function as it's written.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428669/how-to-setup-the-maxrecursion-option-for-a-cte-inside-a-table-valued-function) SO question and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/7c7d5fea-38ad-4bc5-9038-a157e640561f) MSDN discussion for further details and other potential workarounds.

One more comment... If you are expecting long strings, maybe you should consider changing the parameter from `NVARCHAR(4000)` to `NVARCHAR(max)`?

Comment: As per the question, the string is coming from an SSRS multi-valued parameter, which is comma delimited. If the OP confirms they need your specific case I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Just the way I was thinking... Thank you.

Comment: If I supply around more than 100 of those values, I keep getting recursion error, I can't add up OPTION(MAXRECURSION N) why?

Comment: I've applied some more detail to help with your recursion issue.

Comment: Hi Ian, this is perfect, that was I was doing before adding the option hint inside the function, now I understand, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You're welcome! If you find an answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or setting it as the accepted answer.