# Structure Databases for Unknown Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am structuring a set of databases which all interconnect and contain information about each other. One of the main functions of the databases is to record paths and endpoints, for example;

Path 1 crosses endpoints point_1, point_2, point_3, point_4 and point_5

 `Path_1` = `p1-p2-p3-p4-p5`

Path 2 crosses endpoints point_1, point_2 and point_5

 `Path_1` = `p1-p2-p5`

Database Structure:

```
path_id | start_point | point_1 | point_2 | point_3 | end_point |
--------|-------------|---------|---------|---------|-----------|
    1   |     p_1     |   p_2   |   p_3   |   p_4   |    p_5    |
    2   |     p_1     |   p_2   |         |         |    p_5    |
```

And so on...

My problem is that I won't always know how many points it's going to cross. It could be 5 or it could be more than 15. How do I structure a database so that I could allocate a variable amount of points? (Path order is important)

To add to this, each point-point path also have an id associated with it. For example `p1-p2` = `0001` and `p2-p3` = `0002`

Also how would I structure an SQL statement? At some point I want to query all of the paths that cross  specific points, and if I have too many points I'm afraid I don't know how to create a statement so long.

This is probably a wrong database setup for this needs, any other suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Columns represent the metadata and your points are actually data. A better design will possibly be:

```
path_id | point 
--------|-------------
    1   |  p_1     
    1   |  p_2     
    1   |  p_3     
    1   |  p_4  
    1   |  p_5     
    2   |  p_1  
    2   |  p_2     
    2   |  p_5
```

Of course you should consider adding columns for additional information (ie. 'order', if relevant), and a UK for these two columns combined.

A SELECT statement will be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE point = 'p_1';`

Comment: that is not enough OP need to keep order of points in the path (I guess), so you can add 2 other columns like `id` and `nextId`

Comment: You are correct, though it wasn't stated that this is necessary. If it is, I suggested to add an 'order' column (reset for each path_id).

Comment: @Alex Point order is important since a path from p_5 to p_3 is not the same as p_3 to p_5

Answer (score 0):

Using RDBMS for hierarchical data structure (specially infinite loops) is not recommended, its why [graph database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) have been created.
 [Neo4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) will serve your sample in an elegant approach. 
For a relational solution you may use path enumeration pattern.
A UNIX path like `/usr/local/lib/` is a path enumeration of the file system, where usr is the parent of local, which in turn is the parent of lib.
You can create a table containing paths graph(item hierarchy), calling it EnumPath.
[image]

> I want to query all of the paths that cross specific point (like Pn)

```
SELECT EnumPath.PathName from EnumPath
WHERE EnumPath.Path LIKE '%Pn%'
```

Paths starting from Pn:

```
SELECT EnumPath.PathName from EnumPath
WHERE EnumPath.Path LIKE 'Pn%'
```

Paths ending to Pn:

```
SELECT EnumPath.PathName from EnumPath
WHERE EnumPath.Path LIKE '%Pn'
```

> I want to query all of the paths that cross specific points (like Pk and Pi ...)

```
SELECT EnumPath.PathName from EnumPath
WHERE EnumPath.Path LIKE '%Pk%'
AND EnumPath.Path LIKE '%Pi%'
AND ...
```

A more comprehensive answer related to this question may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223333/data-structure-for-many-to-many-hierarchies-in-sql-server/23224653#23224653).