# How to get the value from another row in my query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, view

How to get value from another row in SQL?

```
ID  DeletedPersonID  ProductKey    PartyID       RespID  
9     461               17            33           95      
10    95                17            34           95
```

and I have this select statement

```
select
      drp.ID,
      drp.DeletedPersonID,
      drp.ProductID,
      case when drp.DeletedPersonID != drp.RespID then (Get Party Key by RespID) else drp.PartyID end as 'PartyID',
      case when drp.DeletedPersonID != drp.RespID then (Get Party Key by RespID) else drp.PartyName end as 'PartyName',
      case when drp.DeletedPersonID = drp.RespID then null else drp.PartyID end as 'SubPartyID',
from dbo.RespHistory drp
```

In above example since ID = 10 has the same DeletedPersonID and RespID value I like to use the same PartyID but in `ID = 9` or in the first line Since DeletedPersonID and RespID are difference I want to use PartyID of `ID = 10`

I am looking a view similar to shown below

```
 ID DeletedPersonID  ProductKey    PartyID       PartyName   SubPartyID
   9      461               17            34           ABC      33
  10      95                17            34           XYZ      null
```

Comment: Take a look at the window function `LAG`

Comment: Where is [PartyName] coming from? In order to help we need as many details, you can provide. Also, will the row you need the value from **always** be the immediately preceding row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
with equals_cte (RespID) as (
    select RespID
    from dbo.RespHistory
    where DeletedPersonID = RespID
)
select
    drp.ID, drp.DeletedPersonID, drp.ProductKey, coalesce(ec.RespID, drp.RespID) PartyID
    , drp.PartyName, drp.RespID
    , iif(drp.DeletedPersonID = drp.RespID, null, drp.RespID) SubPartyID
from dbo.RespHistory drp
left join equals_cte ec on drp.RespID = ec.RespID;
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, Can i create a view using `;with equals_cte`? showing me expecting incorrect syntax near ; `( or Select)`

Comment: Yes you can create a view.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172801/ms-sql-server-how-to-create-a-view-from-a-cte)

Comment: FYI, `with` doesn't start with a `;` - `with` just requires the previous statement (if it exists) to be terminated with a `;` which is the recommended way to terminate *ALL* statements in T-SQL.